# Error while printing gloss definitions in python

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I have following list of synsets in python:

```
string = ["Synset('bank.n.01')", "Synset('computer.n.01')", "Synset('work.v.02')", "Synset('super.a.01')"]
```

and I am trying to combine gloss definitions of individual in the following manner:

```
string1 = ""
for w in string:
     string1 = string1 + w.definition
```

But it is giving me following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'definition'
```

But if I do

```
for w in wn.synsets("bank"):
    print w.definition
```

It runs successfully and gives correct result. Please tell me what should I do?

Comment: _"I have following set of synsets in python"_. That's not a set of synsets. That's a list of strings. Perhaps you meant to type each element without the quote marks.

Comment: @Kevin If i am using each element thrugh for loop then it is accessed without double quotes. Then what is the problem?

Comment: You are confusing a list of strings containing characters with actual synset objects in Python (whose printed representation may be equal to those strings; but that does not turn strings into objects of another type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question**: Why do you have Synsets objects as strings?

Native `string` objects in python doesn't have `definition` attribute, they only have these functions/attributes: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

What you need is a `Synset` object from `NLTK`, see http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.html

Going back to your code, what you need is the `key` to access the Synsets, e.g. `bank.n.01`:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> import re
>>> list_of_synsets_in_str = ["Synset('bank.n.01')", "Synset('computer.n.01')", "Synset('work.v.02')", "Synset('super.a.01')"]
>>> losis = list_of_synsets_in_str
>>> [re.findall("'([^']*)'", i)[0] for i in losis]
['bank.n.01', 'computer.n.01', 'work.v.02', 'super.a.01']
```

Then with the key cast it into a `Synset` object:

```
>>> [wn.synset(re.findall("'([^']*)'", i)[0]) for i in losis]
[Synset('bank.n.01'), Synset('computer.n.01'), Synset('work.v.02'), Synset('ace.s.01')]
```

Then you can access the definition from the `wn.synset(x).defintion()`:

```
>>> list_of_synsets = [wn.synset(re.findall("'([^']*)'", i)[0]) for i in losis]
>>> for i in list_of_synsets:
...     print i, i.definition()
... 
Synset('bank.n.01') sloping land (especially the slope beside a body of water)
Synset('computer.n.01') a machine for performing calculations automatically
Synset('work.v.02') be employed
Synset('ace.s.01') of the highest quality
```